# Pass a Header/Cookie in jmeter webdriver

Tags: cookies, selenium-webdriver, header, jmeter

Trying to Pass a hardcoded header into a jmeter webdriver Script

```
var pkg=JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium,org.openqa.selenium.support.ui) 
var Thr=JavaImporter(java.lang.Thread)
var wait = new pkg.WebDriverWait(WDS.browser, 10) 
//var ui=JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium.support.ui) 
WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart() 
var usernameField = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.id('uname')) 
usernameField.sendKeys(['TDM_73312'])
var passwordField = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.id('pw_TLNPI')) 
passwordField.sendKeys(['abcd'])     
WDS.sampleResult.setRequestHeaders('C1_PID:S6VwSlA5ncV0XCUAgwXXrh399zhOZRM9xuIgueFxe2M48GKvRtN2Kd4Dg3zixa0r'+'\n'+'profile_ref_id:S6VwSlA5ncV0XCUAgwXXrh399zhOZRM9xuIgueFxe2M48GKvRtN2Kd4Dg3zixa0r')
Thr.Thread.sleep(2000)
var loginButton=WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.id('login-start-button')) 
loginButton.click() //click on the login button
WDS.log.info(WDS.name + ' has logged an entry')
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
```

I need to pass these 2 header for a successful login

```
WDS.sampleResult.setRequestHeaders('C1_PID:S6VwSlA5ncV0XCUAgwXXrh399zhOZRM9xuIgueFxe2M48GKvRtN2Kd4Dg3zixa0r'+'\n'+'profile_ref_id:S6VwSlA5ncV0XCUAgwXXrh399zhOZRM9xuIgueFxe2M48GKvRtN2Kd4Dg3zixa0r')
```

When I run this script its not successfully logging in

Answer (score 4):

1. Unfortunately you cannot amend HTTP Headers as [it is not possible by WebDriver design](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/141).
2. In order to manipulate cookies you can use [WebDriver.manage().addCookie()](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Options.html#addCookie-org.openqa.selenium.Cookie-) method. Given JavaScript (default language for the WebDriver Sampler) this can be done like:

   ```
   var myCookie = new org.openqa.selenium.Cookie("Cookie_Name","Cookie_Value");
   WDS.browser.manage().addCookie(myCookie);
   ```

See [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-10-questions-answered) article for more WebDriver Sampler tips and tricks